# How to display text on a website from htm or xml file that is updated every time

Tags: javascript, html, xml, stream

I'm working on the radio site and for streaming, the Jazler RadioStar 2 program is used which allows constant updating of files that transmit the information which song is currently streaming..

[check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrBBr.png)

I am specifically interested in how to transfer the title of the song and the name of the author to my homepage..

customexportfile.htm code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Trenutno Slusate!</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>TNowOnAir: <strong>Cher | Believe</strong>

</body>

</html>
```

or via xml file, NowOnAir.xml

```
<Schedule System="Jazler">
<Event status="happening" startTime="09:15:30" eventType="song">
<Announcement Display=""/>
<Song title="Believe">
<Artist name="Cher"> </Artist>
<Jazler ID="6379"/>
<PlayLister ID=""/>
<Media runTime="03:34"/>
<Expire Time="09:19:03"/>
</Song>
</Event>
</Schedule>
```

These files are automatically updated when the song on the stream changes.

Comment: Use ajax to get information from the server without reloading the page

Comment: Can you explain me better, I'm noob in scripting..

Comment: [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) is stand for Asynchronous Javascript And Xml. You can [set timeouts](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) in JavaScript to request data (XML, JSON, text or anything) from server

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you do the code, I'm not a programmer and I do not understand the best of these things..

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a text file to the same directory as `NowOnAir.xml`!
2. Name it like `filename.html`
3. Type the following inside:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>

<body onload="refresh()">

<p>Now playing: <span id="art"></span>|<span id="title"></span>

<script>
var interval,time
function refresh(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("art").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementByTagName("ARTIST")[0].getAttribute("name");
            document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = this.responseXML.getElementByTagName("SONG")[0].getAttribute("title");
            time=this.responseXML.getElementByTagName("EXPIRE")[0].getAttribute("Time").split(":")
            interval=setInterval(checkTime,1000)
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "NowOnAir.xml", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
}
function checkTime(){
    var date=new Date()
    if(date.getSeconds()==time[2]&&date.getMinutes()==time[1]&&date.getHours()==time[0]){
        clearInterval(interval)
        refresh()
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Then try it (you will find it like this: `http://serveraddress/path/filename.html`)

I hope that this will help you!

Comment: I tried this and got two error in the console : https://i.postimg.cc/K85yw7Hc/Capture.png

Comment: Otherwise the site on which I work is on the wordpress platform, if it is something that is important..

Answer (score 0):

Hesitantly, you can try out this code...

**N.B.**

1. There are a great many reasons why this might not work (from the outset, or later).
2. You should certainly test this out in an environment where it will not upset anyone if it doesn't work.
3. The solution below involves checking for a new song and title every 5 seconds using the Javascript setInterval method. That could well be a wholly inappropriate solution because it will run indefinitely every 5 seconds. Without more information, it's impossible to answer this for you really.
4. This code is **untested**.

Anyway, here's a punt at solving this problem:

**HTML (homepage):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Trenutno Slusate!</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p>NowOnAir: 
    <strong>
        <span id="artistName">Cher</span> | 
        <span id="songTitle">Believe</span>
    </strong>
</p>
<script>
    function getNowPlaying() {
        const src = "NowOnAir.xml";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: src,
            dataType: xml,
            success: function(xml) {

            //parse XML
            const xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
            const $doc = $( xmlDoc );
            const $artist = $doc.find( "Artist" ).attr("name").text();
            const $song = $doc.find( "Song" ).attr("title").text();

            //update homepage
            $("#artistName").text($artist);
            $("#songTitle").text($song);

            },
            error: function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        })
    }

    setInterval( function() {
        getNowPlaying();
    }, 5000);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

If it doesn't work, feel free to comment and I'll try to help.